# Integer method is called every time - methodOverloading -java

Tags: java, overloading

I have some confusion in method overloading, can anyone please solve this.

In my sample class i have a method with name display which is overloaded, and the code look like as below.

```
class Sample {
    void display(byte num) {
        System.out.println("under byte");
    }

    void display(short num){
        System.out.println("under short");
    }

    void display(int num) {
        System.out.println("under int");
    }

    void display(long num) {
        System.out.println("under long");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.display(10);
        sample.display(128);
        sample.display(134572);
        sample.display(65757l);
    }
}
```

I'm getting output as

```
under int
under int
under int
under long
```

why even the number is less than 127 also jvm is not calling the method which accepts byte as parameter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: by default numbers are int in java

Comment: For readability, you should avoid `65757l`, but instead use `65757L`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literals of integer value with no suffix are always treated by the compiler as `int` literal. Therefore the `display(int num)` is chosen in the first 3 cases, regardless of the actual value.

In the last case you passed a literal with `l` suffix, which was treated as `long`, which is why the method that accepts a `long` was called.

Answer (score 1):

**byte**: 8-bit signed integer. Can hold values from -128 to 127.
**short**: 16-bit signed integer. Can hold values from -32,768 to 32,767.
**int**: a 32-bit signed integer. Can hold values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
**long**: a 64-bit integer. Can hold really big numbers (-2^63 to 2^63–1).

Normally, conversion from larger data type to lower is not mandatory, the system itself will take care of that but we have to mention explicitly for converting lower data type to higher.

To override all the methods in your code. Try this

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
sample.display((byte)10);
sample.display((short)128);
sample.display(134572);
sample.display(65757l);
```

Answer (score 0):

> why even the number is less than 127 also jvm is not calling the method which accepts byte as parameter?

Because the type of the literal 127 is `int` (as per [JLS 15.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1)). The `int` type cannot be implicitly converted to `byte` or `short`, so the first two overloads are incompatible. The method with the `int` parameter is *more specific* ([JLS 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) than the method with the `long` parameter, which is why it's chosen, except for your last example which uses a `long` argument instead due to having a literal ending with `l`. (As an aside, I'd recommend using `L` as the suffix instead of `l`; it's clearer IMO.)

There's a difference here between calling a method and assigning to a variable. This is okay:

```
byte b = 127;
```

because 127 is a constant expression being assigned to `byte`, and it's known to be a valid value for the byte. This is an *assignment context*, and the valid conversions for assignment contexts are specified in [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

When making a method call, the conversion from argument type to parameter type is *not* deemed an assignment context. Instead, this is an *invocation context* ([JLS 5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)). This was a choice of the Java language designers - the language could have been designed in a way that allowed it, but it isn't. This difference is called out within JLS 5.3:

> Neither strict nor loose invocation contexts include the implicit narrowing of integer constant expressions which is allowed in assignment contexts. The designers of the Java programming language felt that including these implicit narrowing conversions would add additional complexity to the rules of overload resolution (§15.12.2).

Answer (score 0):

[The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

> For byte, from -128 to 127, inclusive
>
> For short, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
>
> For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
>
> For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
>
> For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to
>   65535

And an integral value are of type long if you explicit use a suffix `l` or `L` ([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1))

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

So effectively, you're calling your `int` overloaded version when passing those int:

```
    sample.display(10);
    sample.display(128);
    sample.display(134572);
```

If you want, for example, call `short` overloaded version, you must first narrowing down the value:

```
 sample.display((short) 10);
```

Comment: this range is configurable btw...

Answer (score 0):

*You need to  clarify the `type` of **integer** numbers or it will always treated the number as `int`. (except larger numbers)*

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the numbers as variables first with its correct type and the pass them throug the method and you would see the change:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        byte a = 10;
        shot b = 128;
        int c = 134572;
        long d = 65757lL;
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.display(a);
        sample.display(b);
        sample.display(c);
        sample.display(d);
    }
```

If you dont declare the type, the compiler will interpret the variables as it thinks opportune

Answer (score 0):

Default data type of a whole number in Java is integer and hence every call is delegated to method which accepts parameter of type int.

If you want to invoke other methods, you can either type cast the value to that type during method invocation or you can declare a variable of that type and pass that variable during method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 fundamentals from your question:

1. **Literals**:
   If you write sample.display(10), by default Java compiler considers the number 10 as an integer literal of the int variable type.
2. **Overloading**:
   You have 4 overloaded methods that have single argument. When a value is passed to the method the compiler will pick up the one that has argument data type nearest to the input value type. In this case, the compiler will execute display(int num) for first 3 calls because the input values are integer literals. The fourth one will execute display(long num) because because the input value is a long.
3. **Casting**: 
   If you want the display(byte num) and display(short numb) to be executed you need to downcast the input value of int type to byte and short. Because downcasting from an int to a byte or short is a narrowing conversion therefore you must do it explicitly.

   ```
   sample.display(10) -> sample.display((byte)10);
   sample.display(128) -> sample.display((short)128);
   ```